# Does "slept" as in "had sex" have a PP argument?

Tags: syntax, english, phrasal-verbs

"Sleep" is clearly monovalent:

> They slept.

But, is the colloquial usage of "sleep" to mean "had sex with" a divalent verb with a PP argument or is "sleep with" a phrasal verb?

> Richard slept with her.

I'm hesitant about calling it a phrasal verb because it can be reflexive without "with." Is this even a deciding factor for testing for phrasal verbs?

> They slept together.

For example, to take another phrasal verb, "passed for," two twins would say (1), not (2).

> 1. We passed for each other yesterday.
> 2. *We passed each other yesterday.

Answer (score 4):

"sleep with" is not a phrasal verb.  If it were, one could say *"He slept her with", and one could not move the "with" phrase as a unit, as in "With whom has he slept?".  Compare the phrasal verb "dust off": "He dusted it off", *"Off what did he dust?"

So, yes, the "with NP" is a PP.  (And two race car drivers could say "We passed each other repeatedly".)

Comment: I'm not sure I follow. You can't say *"He dusted off it" which you argue is a phrase verb?

Comment: That's right, taking the term "phrasal verb" to mean the same as "particle verb".  Those verbs require a pronoun object to occur immediately after the verb and before the particle.  I have no opinion about whether a "phrasal verb" is actually in some sense a phrase.  I use the term in a classificatory sense -- it refers to a certain construction which is clearly different from a verb+ PP construction.

Comment: So I don't know much about particle verbs, but at least one paper (http://journals.cambridge.org/abstract_S1360674314000197) seems fine with "the alternative structure with the particle immediately following the verb (*v V prt O*)," (574) a "variant [realization] of a single lexeme whose morphological or syntactic status is underspecified' (577).

Comment: Did you read what I wrote?  A **pronoun** object has to come immediately after a particle verb and before the particle.  That's not a theory -- it's a fact.

Comment: Yes I did. Can you cite that then? That was one of the papers I found trying to research your statement.

Comment: Well, I suppose I could refer you to Ross's **Constraints on Variables in Syntax** (I think John Lawler has an online copy on his website) or Bruce Fraser's MIT dissertation.  But, really, it's not the sort of thing that needs a scholarly reference.  It's a fact of English.  Construct some appropriate examples and ask any native English speaker about them.  It's as simple as that.

Comment: Thanks. I'm just trying to understand, I'm not trying to be combative. Is there a name for the addition of a PP modifying the meaning of the verb like this? E.g. `sleep`/`sleep with` or `fuck`/`fuck with`?

Comment: As I understand the terms, the "with"-PP completes the meaning of "sleep" in this construction, rather than modifying it.  A long time ago, George Lakoff wrote a little paper claiming that the subject of "Tom and Joyce slept together" is a deep structure conjunction of NPs, as opposed to the result of Conjunction Reduction applying to "Tom slept and Joyce slept." (These are not Lakoff's originall examples.) Then there was a transformation to derive the "with" phrase from the second of the conjoined NPs.  I think Lakoff's paper was in ...

Comment: ... **NSF-17 Report to the NSF of the Harvard Computation Laboratory**.

Comment: I agree that in 'sleep with x', 'with x' looks like an argument, since it changes the meaning of the verb, but 'sleep' does not need the 'with x' complement to mean 'have sex with + unspecified sex partner': in 'Richard has been sleeping around too much of late' 'sleep around' has exactly that meaning. That suggests to me that 'sleep', 'sleep with' and 'sleep around'  must all be included in the lexicon as different lexical items.

Comment: Sure.  And yet another lexical entry for "The new CEO slept her way through the entire board of directors."